# r equivalent of group by with cube

Tags: r

Some sql databases [support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175939%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) a `with cube` modifier to `group by` operations. Mine doesn't have this feature.

Basically if I have a dataset like:

```
+------+-----------+---------+---------+
| sum  | source_id | type_id | variety |
+------+-----------+---------+---------+
|  491 |         1 |       1 |       1 |
| 2008 |         1 |       2 |       1 |
|   33 |         1 |       3 |       1 |
|  483 |         1 |       4 |       1 |
|  482 |         1 |       5 |       1 |
|  343 |         1 |       6 |       1 |
| 4979 |         4 |       5 |       1 |
|  303 |         5 |       1 |       1 |
|  443 |         5 |       1 |       2 |
| 1295 |         5 |       2 |       1 |
...
```

I want to import this into a data frame in r and generate the combined sum for all sub-permutations of (source_id, type_id, and variety). So, the combined sum where source_id=1, where source_id=1 and type_id=1, where source_id=1 and variety=1, where type_id=1 and variety=1, where type_id=1, where source_id=2, and so on.

How can I best accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use ddply for this, and input a list with the possible combinations, like this :

```
facs <- c("source_id","type_id","variety")

combs <-  unlist(
            mapply(function(j)combn(facs,j,simplify=F),1:3)
          ,recursive=F)

require(plyr)
datlist <- mapply(function(j)ddply(Data,j,summarize,sum(Sum)),combs)

require(reshape)
rbind.fill(datlist)
```

Tested with :

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Sum=rpois(10,5),
  source_id=rep(1:2,each=5),
  type_id=rep(1:5,each=2),
  variety=rep(1:2,5)
)
```

Comment: @Joris. there seems to be a bug in your method. I tried `set.seed(1234)` and ran your code. The first line corresponding to the sum of `source_id = 1` is 47, when looking at the actual data it is 26. In fact 47 is the sum of `source_id = 1` and `source_id = 2`

Comment: @Joris. quick correction makes your code work. replace your function with `ddply(Data, j, summarize, sum(Sum))`. Not specifying what to sum explicitly is causing the problem I suppose.

Comment: @Ramnath : and on second thought, I don't really need mapply here, I can just do it with lapply as well.

Comment: @hadley: thx for the tip, count looks very interesting. But I'm not sure I see where I can use it here...

Comment: It's equivalent to your ddply - it also does weighted counts

Comment: @hadley : ah, I see the confusion. I made a rather stupid mistake in my original code. OP didn't need the counts, but the sum of another variable. But thx again for the tip.

Comment: @hadley: true, I didn't see it that way. Thx for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
# generate dummy data

df = data.frame(
       Sum = rnorm(10), 
       source_id = sample(10, 5, replace = T), 
       type_id   = sample(10, 5, replace = T), 
       variety   = sample(10, 5, replace = T)
     )

index = names(df)[-1]
temp  = expand.grid(0:1, 0:1, 0:1)[-1,]

require(plyr)
cubedf = adply(temp, 1, function(x) 
   ddply(df, index[x == 1], summarize, SUM = sum(Sum)))
```

EDIT: ALTERNATE SOLUTION (using code borrowed from Joris)

```
library(plyr)
# list factor variables
index  = names(df)[-1]

# generate all combinations of factor variables
combs  = unlist(llply(1:3, combn, x = index, simplify = F), recursive = F)

# calculate sum for each combination
cubedf = ldply(combs, function(var) 
            ddply(df, var, summarize, SUM = sum(Sum)))
```

Comment: nice demonstration of the plyr capacities

Answer (score 1):

Joris's Answer is right. But I must admit that it's not intuitive to me at first blush. Prior to reading his answer, I would have solved this with multiple `ddply()` steps. Something like this:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  Sum=rpois(10,5),
  source_id=rep(1:2,each=5),
  type_id=rep(1:5,each=2),
  variety=rep(1:2,5)
)

require(plyr)

myStuff1 <- ddply(Data, c("source_id"                      ), function(df) sum(df$Sum) )
myStuff2 <- ddply(Data, c("source_id", "type_id"           ), function(df) sum(df$Sum) )
myStuff3 <- ddply(Data, c("source_id", "type_id", "variety"), function(df) sum(df$Sum) )
```

Comment: See also the add_margins function